# Which one will definitely change?

Tags: statistics, means, median

> If you change only one observation from a set of 10 observations, which of the following will definitely change?
>
> 1. Mean
> 2. Median
> 3. Mode
> 4. Standard deviation

my answer: i assumed that all 10 observations are equal then mean, median & mode will be equal and the standard deviation will be zero but when i change one observation, there will be probable change in all four quantities, but i am not sure which one will definitely change. please help me by explaining the answer.

Comment: the mean is linear in every entry, so it changes if you keep 9 fixed and change just one.

Comment: can you please explain why median, mode & standard deviation won't change?

Comment: It isn't that they necessarily won't change, only that they won't definitely change.  For example, in the data set $\{0,1,1,1,1,2\}$ the mode is $1$ and will stay $1$ after you change some single datum.  For the set $\{0,2,4,6\}$ the median is $3$...can you see how to change one datum without changing the median?  Standard deviation is harder to contact an example for, but it is possible.

Comment: Hint (for standard deviation):  Start with the set $\{-1,0,1\}$  Now change the last data point...so we get $\{-1,0,1+3x\}$  where I write $3x$ so that the new mean is $x$.  Now, solve for $x$ to leave $\sigma$ unchanged.

Comment: An even easier example for standard deviation: $\{0,0,1\}$ changed to $\{0,1,1\}$.

Comment: While example's like @Arthur's where the SD doesn't change are possible, the SD is very often changed. Median is often unchanged, especially if there are ties at the median; always unchanged if new and old values are on the same side of the median.

Comment: @BruceET What you say about median is almost true. For $\{0,1,3,6\}$ transformed into $\{0,1,4,6\}$, we have that $3$ and $4$  are in the same side of the median, but the median changes.

Comment: OK. But it depends on the definition of the median, which differs depending on text and software. Might claim that 1 is median in both of your sets.